# How to loop PL/SQL a:=a+2;

Tags: sql, loops, for-loop, plsql, syntax-error

```
DECLARE

a number(20):=5;
BEGIN
    FOR a in 1..20 LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('value: '|| a);

    a:=a+2;

    END LOOP;

    END;
```

Error is :

> Error report: ORA-06550: line 8, column 5: PLS-00363: expression 'A'
>   cannot be used as an assignment target ORA-06550: line 8, column 5:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

How can i do that?

Comment: Declare a variable outside of the for loop and use that one instead of a.

Comment: I think, what you want to achieve is better done with a `WHILE`-Loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `a` in the for loop is a for loop index and is read only.
Note that `a` in the for loop is declared implicitly and is not the same variable as `a` in the `declare` section.

This is explained in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS411).

If you want to modify the value of your variable `a` inside the loop simply give the for loop index another name:

```
DECLARE
a number(20):=5;
BEGIN
    -- Note that no declaration of b is necessary
    FOR b in 1..20 LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('value: '|| a);
        a:=a+2;
    END LOOP;
END;
```